# Error during installation of giter8 using Home-brew

Tags: homebrew, giter8

I've been trying to install `giter8` using `brew`, like so:
`brew install giter8`

I get the following error:
`Error: giter8 has been disabled because it fetches unversioned dependencies at runtime!`

Does anybody know how to fix this, or what workarounds are available. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `giter8` formula is disabled https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/8eb269a6a9bbb207e3c39efef8afd12b9bff83de#diff-8fe00c16c6b04f6109b083bfa0d196e87a7f9c8684c5720727a5b069a25453eb

Answer (score 5):

This worked as a workaround for me. No idea if that's the proper fix

Edit the brew formula for giter8:

```
brew edit giter8
```

and delete this line

```
  disable! because: "fetches unversioned dependencies at runtime"
```

The default editor will be vim -- put cursor at that line and hit `dd` to delete then type `:x` to save and exit

then re-run `brew install giter8` and you should be good

Answer (score 4):

You can create giter8 projects with SBT directly and don't need to install giter8 via Homebrew anymore.  `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` is the example [in the docs](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/).

[This thread](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/issues/475) has another workaround (@alexroussos solution also works).

Answer (score 1):

Install giter8

```
brew install --build-from-source giter8
```

Comment: https://brewinstall.org/install-giter8-on-mac-with-brew/